# Qual a forma correta de dizer: "Vende-se lotes" ou "vendem-se lotes"?

Tags: expressões, significado-em-contexto, número-gramatical

Qual a forma correta de dizer :Vende-se lotes ou vendem-se lotes.
Fica no plural ou no singular ?

Comment: *Vendem-se lotes*. A frase está na *voz passiva sintética*; logo, o verbo deve concordar com o *sujeito paciente*. Se transformarmos a frase em *voz passiva analítica*, teremos *Lotes são vendidos*.

Comment: Já vi das duas formas: "Vendem-se lotes" e "Vende-se lotes"

Comment: O verbo *vender* é transitivo direto; portanto, não é possível afirmar que o *se* seja um índice de indeterminação do sujeito.

Comment: Uma pergunta muito comum em provas de nível médio:  qual a forma correta "aluga-se casas" ou "alugam-se casas" ?  Basta passar a frase para a voz passiva analítica, conforme sugere @ValdeirPsr: "casas são alugadas". Portanto, "alugam-se casas"

Comment: Como assim, @Centaurus , «basta passar a frase para a voz passiva analítica»? Não percebo como é que "casas são alugadas" implica "aluga**m**-se casas". Botem esta faladura toda em respostas, para eu vos aplicar up- e down-votes adequadamente. ;)

Comment: Vá, escrevam uma resposta, para eu comentar "[Alice] Aqui vende-se. [Bob] Vende-se o quê? [Alice] Casas... aqui vende-se casas."

Comment: @ANeves  Em outras palavras,  em expressões como ***alugam-se casas, consertam-se geladeiras, vendem-se carros***, ou seja,  na voz passiva sintética, o termo que vem após o verbo é o sujeito, e o verbo deve então concordar com ele.

Comment: @ANeves   No entanto, a outra forma como tentei explicar o fenômeno, também funciona.  **Alugam-se casas** traz a mesma informação que **casas são alugadas**.  Jà **"aluga-se casas"**, está errado porque não pode ser transformado em "casas **é** alugadas.